# androidのadb shell上で得られた出力結果をPCに保存したい

Tags: android, bash

以下のようなコマンドで /proc/sys/net/ipv4 配下のファイルすべてを cat しています。
cat の結果を /Users/hoge/Desktop/hoe/para.txt しようと考えています。

```
adb shell
ff() { for p in "$@"; do [ -d "$p" ] && { ff "$p"/*; continue; }; echo "$p"; done; }
ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4
ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4 |while read f; do echo "$f"",\c"; cat  "$f"; done >> /Users/hoge/Desktop/hoge/para.csv
```

これをスクリプトにしようと、`>>` で追記先を記載してみましたが、adb shell 上で実行しているため、保存先が Android 端末内となっていまい、以下のエラーメッセージが表示されてしまい困っております。

```
/system/bin/sh: can't create /Users/hoge/Desktop/hoe/para.txt: No such file or directory
```

補足

> > @user3009331さま
> >     申し訳ございません、当方のコードに誤りがあり、ご教示いただいた方法に基づき、下記のコードで無事動作いたしました。回答の復活をお願いできませんでしょうか。

```
adb shell
ff() { for p in "$@"; do [ -d "$p" ] && { ff "$p"/*; continue; }; echo "$p"; done; }
ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4
ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4 |while read f; do echo "$f"",\c"; cat "$f"; done > /sdcard/temp.csv
exit
adb pull /sdcard/temp.csv /Users/hoge/Desktop/para.csv
```

Comment: `adb shell > localfile.txt` もしくは、 `adb shell | tee localfile.txt` で adb を起動してはどうですか？ （cat 内容だけではなく受け取った内容全てが保存されるでしょうが）

Comment: @user3009331 user3009331 さんに回答の復活を頼んだ方が良いのではないでしょうか（賛成票を入れたいと思いますので）。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下の方法は如何でしょうか。ワンラインです。
adb pullするのではなく、出力を直接ファイル化しています。

> adb shell "ff() { for p in \"$@\"; do [ -d \"$p\" ] && { ff \"$p\"/*; continue; }; echo \"$p\"; done; }; ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4 | while read f; do echo $f;cat $f; done" > para.txt

para.txtの部分はローカルパスになります。

Comment: エラーメッセージは出ないのですが、作成されたpara.txtが空になってしまいました。

Comment: すみません。adb shellを実行する側の環境に依存します。  
"ff()～done"をダブルクォーテーションではなくシングルクォーテーションにして、括られた中のエスケープを全て外す(\"⇒")とpara.txtに出力されると思います。

Comment: ありがとうございます。コメントいただきました方法で動作いたしました。

adb shell 'ff() { for p in "$@"; do [ -d "$p" ] && { ff "$p"/*; continue; }; echo "$p"; done; }; ff /proc/sys/net/ipv4 | while read f; do echo $f;cat $f; done' > para3.txt